# what is the theory behind matlab butter function?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I would like to know the theory behind matlab butter function. Is there any book which gives clear idea on how it works. In future I would like to calculate the coefficients manually.

Comment: Your question is not about programming, dsp.stackexchange.com is the better place to ask this. If n00dle did not answer your question fully, I recommend to ask a more detailed question there, explaining what you did not understand.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you've looked at the [Matlab help page](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html).

### Background

It's an implementation of the "Butterworth Filter". There's some quite in-depth information on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter). You could also look into the way an actual [electronics circuit](http://www.ece.uic.edu/~jmorisak/blpf.html) would be made up.

The basic idea is you have some frequencies (or equivalently wavelengths) that you want to allow, and some that you want to block. Quoting Wikipedia:

> "An ideal electrical filter should not only completely reject the unwanted frequencies but should also have uniform sensitivity for the wanted frequencies"

So you want all desired frequencies (passband) to go through the filter with equal transmission AND all non-desired frequencies to have zero transmission. (Here transmission means how much of the signal gets through the filter).

The Butterworth filter manages the former well - it is maximally flat, it couldn't be flatter. However, the drop-off from the passband can be quite slow, so it lets some other frequencies through (albeit dampened).

The wikipedia page I linked has quite a nice diagram illustrating it in comparison with other filters:

[image: Filter comparison]

### Improving the Drop-off (Parameter 1)

You can take higher order filters to improve the drop-off (see [Transfer Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter#Transfer_function) section of the wiki). This is the first parameter of the function. Essentially, the higher the order, the sharper the decline from the cutoff frequency to zero transmission.

Again, from Wikipedia:
[image: Varying filter cutoff at different orders]

### The Cut-Off Frequency (Parameter 2)

The cutoff frequency is the point at which you want the filter to stop allowing data through. In the case of a low-pass filter, this means that everything of higher frequency that that will get set to zero (or close to it, depending on the filter order).

You could think of this in an imaging sense. You have a greyscale image with values between 0 and 255. A lowpass filter, set at 128, would keep all image values under and at 128 the same as the input image. Everything else would get set to zero (or some value of your choosing).

### Transfer Function Coefficients

**G_0 - DC Gain**

This is the amount of gain for frequencies that get through your filter. Those within the pass-band (i.e. below the cutoff in the case of a low-pass filter) will have this amount of gain.

**w_c - Cutoff Frequency**

Essentially the frequency at which you stop letting through the signal. This is a slight over-simplification, in fact [it's the frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency) at which gain falls below -3db.